# SQL Server 2012 EXEC sp_spaceused System Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using *SQL Server 2012*, in this I want to obtain informations about the Store volume in the several data Tables. Therefore I use this query:

```
USE msdb;                                   --DATABASE
EXEC sp_spaceused 'people';--TABLENAME
```

This is only working for tables that I have defined.

But how can I have access to System tables like sys.trace_xe_action_map

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select sum(au.total_pages)
from sys.system_internals_partitions p
join sys.system_internals_allocation_units au 
     on au.container_id = p.partition_id
where p.object_id = object_id('sys.trace_xe_event_map');
```

Comment: I don't have access to the sys. namespace

Comment: Then you don't have access to do what you want to do. Create a stored procedure that runs this query, ask an administrator to review it, approve it and sign it for you. See [Module Signing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102(v=sql.105).aspx).